# Paypal After Updating a Billing Plan Amount

Tags: paypal

I have this monthly subscription and I will be making use of the Paypal Rest API SDKs available in this link:
http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/#billing

My question is that, If I updated the billing plan amount, what happens to the users(or billing agreements) subscribing to the old billing plan? Do they pay the updated plan amount in the next billing cycle?

thanks.

Comment: Would love to know the answer to this as well.

Comment: Actually I tried to update the billing plan amount with C# sdk, and it wasn't possible through the new API. It looks this is only possible for the classic API.